# If $y=\frac{x^2+1}{2x+3}$, evaluate $\frac{dy}{dx}$

Tags: derivatives

Solving it would give 
$$\frac{(2x-3)(2x)-(x^2+1)(2)}{(2x+3)^2}$$
$$=\frac{2x^2-6x-2}{(2x+3)^2}$$
I don’t think it’s possible to move ahead from here. The answer is $$\frac{6x-2}{(2x+3)^2}$$
I have serious doubts that the answer given is wrong, but I would like to verify it here nonetheless. Thanks a lot as always.

Comment: wrong sign on the first term of the numerator: should be $2x + 3$ and not $2x - 3$

Comment: Yes, I was being dumb. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Your recent edit made my answer pointless. Please refrain from editing a question once an answer is posted.

Comment: Of course. It was a typo, so I figured I would correct it. I will cancel the edit if you want it.

Comment: I have already done that

Comment: Yeah, no problem.

Answer (score 1):

$$y'=\frac{(2x\color{red}+3)(2x)-(x^2+1)(2)}{(2x+3)^2}=\frac{2(x^2+3x-1)}{(2x+3)^2}$$

Comment: But that still does not give he right answer

Comment: The book's answer is wrong!

Comment: @Aditya you may verify [here](https://www.derivative-calculator.net/#expr=%28x%5E2%2B1%29%2F%282x%2B3%29)